# problem with bibliography perhaps a missing item

Tags: bibtex, miktex

I am trying to produce a bibliography , using acl16 style. the code is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{acl2016}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\cite{Gusfield:97}
\bibliographystyle{acl2016}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

And I get the error:! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. 
In addition: Citation Gusfield:97 on page 1 is undefined. The bib file (example.bib) is--

```
\bibitem[\protect\citename{Gusfield}1997]{Gusfield:97}
Dan Gusfield.
\newblock 1997.
\newblock {\em Algorithms on Strings, Trees and Sequences}.
\newblock Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK.
```

I am using MikTex 2.9 and texmaker. The bbl produces only:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I assume that you have a `.bib` file?

Comment: yes,  the \bibliography{example}--second code block

Comment: Please add this `example.bib` to the post above. Otherwise, we can't reproduce (if at all)

Comment: the `.bib` file you show is really the `.bbl` output of a `.bib` file in a differently tagged format.  although it won't reconstruct the original `.bib` file, if you rename `example.bib` to `example.bbl` you should get reasonable output from your latex run.

Comment: I don't think that this will work. This is no valid `.bib` file!

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Isn't the '.bib' file above already in the format that the `bibliography' environment would understand?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- yes it's in that format, but `thebibliography` reads in a `.bbl` file, not a `.bib` file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I am no `bib` expert, but  in this case, the content of the (wrongly named) `.bib` file could be included directly to the `thebibliography` environment? (Just an assumption)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- bingo!  you are absolutely correct!

Comment: @barbarabeeton: In this case, you should provide an answer, in my point of view...

Comment: Thank you both. I changed to the correct format of .bib file and was finally able to produce the output. I am not sure I understand the subtleties of the .bbl file, but thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the contents of the bibliography as shown are in the format of a `.bbl` file,
which is the output when a `.bib` file is run through bibtex.

two approaches are possible:

- wrap `\begin{thebibliography} ... \end{thebibliography}` around this code
  and insert it into your tex file in place of `\bibliography{example}`
- reconstruct the `.bib` file in the required format and rerun bibtex.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It seemed like for no apparent reason latex file did not compile, giving me the same error, although I had implemented everything correctly. I also checked many posts here but none of them solved my issue.

**Solution:**

The way I solved it was to delete the .bbl file and compiled again. You need to have at least one citation for this to work properly. otherwise again a corrupt .bbl file will be generated. I don't know why is it happening, but maybe at some point when you make a mistake in referencing a corrupted empty .bbl file is created. And even when you fix the mistake it just stays there and the compiler is not able to overwrite it. It is apparently a very common issue and I hope somebody finds the issue and fixes it.

Comment: I don't think, that this is the same problem. The problem of user1807435 was a  broken `bib`-file. With a broken `bib`-file rerunning `bibtex` or `biber` doesn't help. If you really have the same error message from time to time and regeneration of `bbl`-file helps, you could have an mistake in your `bib`-file, that only sometimes result in an broken `bib`-file, or your previous `bibtex` (or `biber`) run could have been aborted (or something completely different). I don't think, this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is deleting all the **main.*** files except for **main.tex**, and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and i just given the bibliography manually one by one

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.